# rtrim not working string with html elements

Tags: php, html, trim

I have a problem with `rtrim()` function in php. I have string like this one:

```
$str = "<a id="AccountDocument_11" href="/view/id/11">Picture of Collateral</a> [2017-04-01],";
```

Like this, embed the string in array. 
I want to remove that last comma in this string. rtrim not working.
 When i remove that html elements from that string, `rtrim()` works perfectly. anyone help?

Comment: If rtrim isn't working, then it means that the comma isn't the last character in your string; do a var_dump() of the value to see what it contains

Comment: This string should give syntax error

Comment: The string you provided is not properly escaped and when it is, it works OK with `rtrim()`. So, provide the string that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change your string like this, then it will work, it does not work because your string is inappropriate:

```
$str = "<a id='AccountDocument_11' href='/view/id/11'>Picture of 
Collateral</a> [2017-04-01],";
echo rtrim($str,",");
```

output is:

```
Picture of Collateral [2017-04-01]
```

The only difference is that double quoted strings interpret embedded variables and a number of escape sequences, while single quoted strings do not. E.g.:

Reference: [When should you use single or double quotes in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305869/when-should-you-use-single-or-double-quotes-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

write your code below it works

you have write `string ""(double quote)` and under `string` you also used "" string instead of this you use `''(single quote);`

```
<?php
$str = "<a id='AccountDocument_11' href='/view/id/11'>Picture of Collateral</a> [2017-04-01],";

echo rtrim($str,",");
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe you quoted the string wrong.

try the below:

```
$str = rtrim('<a id="AccountDocument_11" href="/view/id/11">Picture of Collateral</a> [2017-04-01],',',');
echo $str;
```